What tools are available to obtain SSL certs from a CA for an isolated/airgapped system?
In the past, I have been able to leave the peculiarities of SSL certs to others, an mostly depend on self-signed certificates. That day has come to a close.
I need to step up and configure a secured but not airgapped (it can reach out, but nothing can reach in) cluster of servers built around RHEL/CentOS with validated SSL certs. There is no web server (nginx, apache, etc) on any of the machines, only internal application service invocations over SSL.
I have empirically confirmed that self-signed certificates are not accepted by the software.
All of the tools I have found so far require the server to be exposed (to the CA signing authority to confirm its authenticity I suppose), but by design we have no pathway from the outside world into the cluster being secured.
If it makes a difference, I am trying to obtain certs from zerossl.com. But I really don't care where they come from.
My most recent attempt was this:
acme.sh --issue -d dev-9-myserver.mydomain.com --standalone --debug

The final output of the tool says status is pending, prior to timing out after 30 retries.
We cannot be the only people in the world who are applying SSL certificates to systems that are not exposed to the internet, so I'm looking for some direction.
What tools are available to obtain certs from a CA for an isolated/airgapped system?
Thank you in advance!

I'm not sure what you are trying to do: Use public domains which you own internally with certificate issued by a public CA? Use public domains which you don't own internally with certificates issued by a public CA - not possible. Use private domains with certificate issued by a public CA - not possible. Use private domains with certificate issued by your own internal CA?

If you're enrolling from a public CA (as your use of acme.sh implies) then why not use ACME's DNS challenge?  That does not expect you to expose any ports.

We own the domain "mycompany.net" (sanitized, of course).  With few very specific exceptions, servers in that domain can reach out to the internet, but by company policy are not allowed to be exposed to the internet.
The application software runs on a cluster of VM's. The members of the cluster communicate via TLS.
By default, the software installs single nodes with self-signed certificates. This works for a demo setup with a single node. But strict certificate checking is always on for cluster members talking to each other.
I hope to avoid having to configure an internal CA.

@garethTheRed the internal servers are not registered on external DNS servers ... or will the acme client validate against our DNS server?

A public CA can only certify things it can verify.  If all your servers have entries in the public DNS, you can use ACME DNS.  If you don't have entries then the CA has nothing to verify - therefore a public CA can't/won't issue.  Your only option is to operate an internal CA and define your own process for verifying the identity, authentication and authority of your subscribers.  That takes knowledge to do properly, which by your own admission, you don't have - so tread carefully.

Issue wildcard certificate for your domain and use on these "internal" machines.

This is one solution under consideration.  Thank you!

@RomeoNinov post this as an answer so we can close this.
The final solution was acme.sh --issue --dns dns_ionos -d '*.mydomain.com'

Enrolling for a wildcard certificate using a public facing machine, then cloning the certificate and private key to all internal machines is just as bad as using self-signed certificates, in that it provides no certification of identity.  It merely ticks the "no self-signed certificates" box.  Relying-parties (the users) are led into a false sense of security because it's from a trusted CA, whereas in reality the private key is being passed around like a new puppy and therefore is not trustworthy at all.  This isn't the purpose of wildcard certificates.

There are scenarios where this is an acceptable tradeoff - my use case (an internal development system with no sensitive data) happens to be one of them. The only reason we can't run with the self-signed certificate in this case is that the software will not accept it. It may not be acceptable for a usecase where server level bindings are required.  I'll leave that discussion for the security gurus.

Absolutely - if only you had mentioned development in your question ;-)  But in a dev environment, I'd have just cobbled together an internal CA myself.  However, your point is more than valid.

One possible way is to use so named wildcard certificates. Such certificate will work on all the machines in you domain (but not on subdomains). This certificate should be issued from the machine, accessible via internet (for validation) or via web interface of the CA. You can use this page as reference (details depend of your CA).
P.S. As per comment the command, used, can be:
acme.sh --issue --dns dns_ionos -d '*.mydomain.com'


As @garethTheRed says, using a wildcard cert may offer little security over a self-signed certificate. There are scenarios where this is an acceptable tradeoff - my use case (an internal development system with no sensitive data) happens to be one of them. The only reason we can't run with the self-signed certificate in this case is that the software will not accept it. It may not be acceptable for a usecase where server level bindings are required.  I'll leave that discussion for the security gurus. Where this tradeoff is not acceptable, your shop will need to set up its own CA

Sadly, my downvote was over nine hours ago which means I'm not allowed to undo it - I never knew.  Now that the fact that this is in a development environment has been mentioned, then it's a different story altogether and this would be more than acceptable and would avoid having to stand up an internal CA.  If I could undo it, I would :-)

No problem.  You had a legitimate concern, one which I will be taking into account when I install a production environment. As you noted, I'm learning the SSL world as I go, so this information (and conversation) is critical not only to me but to future readers of the question. Where there is a DEV environment, there will be a future prod environment.
